# Inserting selected data from table in one schema into another table in a different schema

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table A in Schema1 and table B in Schema2.

The tables have different columns.

## Table A:

```
ID1            Name         Code
-------------------------------
1              Skyler        A0
2              Amanda        A1
3              Rachel        B0
4              Harvey        C0
5              Louis         B1
```

## Table B:

```
ID          Names      Enterprise      Modified_Date
------------------------------------------------------
1             Amanda             1        2018.08.10

2             Skyler             1        2018.08.11
```

As depicted, Schema1.A.Name = Schema2.B.Names

I want to insert the values "Rachel,Harvey and Louis" from A.Name into B.Names.

For b.ID, i have a sequence in place. Enterprise column is always 1 and modified date can e sysdate.

How can i achieve this in PL/SQL?

Comment: how do you know that Table A doesn't have duplicate names? they would not be moved to table B using the solutions that are being proposed. does this matter or is it  a factor?

Comment: also.. when you say that you want to insert "Rachel", "Harvey" and "Louis" to table B... I'm reading that as you want to insert anything into Table B that is not already there... rather than you actually only want to insert Rachel, Harvey and Louis.

Comment: Yes, i am inserting the data into table B that is not there already.

Answer (score 2):

use insert Statement with select statement

```
insert into tabB (names,Enterprise,Modified_Date )
select Name,1,sysdate from tabA where Name         in ('Rachel','Harvey','Louis');
```

Comment: The real table A has more tan 10K records that needs to be inserted to table B. So, can i do it using cursor FOR loop ?

Comment: 10k is nothing. Looping is the wrong way, you should do it with an insert like in my example

Comment: 10k rows changes things in my mind... surely not all 10k rows are unique names. depends on what the end goal that you are trying to achieve if this is a factor or not.

Comment: I created a temp table with the data from table A (Unique values, 11K+ rows) that needs to be inserted into table B . This temp table has only one column 'Name' that needs to be populated in the 'Names' column of table B. Can you help me with the insert statement ?  Can it be a simple insert into statement as i will insert only one column of the table B from the temp table and the rest are from a sequence and some standard values.

Comment: insert into tabB (ID, names,Enterprise,Modified_Date )
select (Sequence1,Name,1,sysdate )from tabA where Name     in ('Rachel','Harvey','Louis');    Will this work ? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using below query.

insert into tableB (names,Enterprise,Modified_Date )
                                             select Name,1,sysdate from tableA where Name  not in (select distinct(Name) from tableB);